# Delay setState in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Here in my application, it has a pull to refresh component. So I used [react-native-pull-to-refresh](https://github.com/moschan/react-native-pull-to-refresh) component. Here in that documentation, it has mentioned that `_refresh` has been set to 2000 delay.

```
_refresh: function() {
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(()=>{resolve()}, 2000)
});
```

But I want to re-render the screen after 2000 delay.

**What I came up with**

```
_refresh(context) {
let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve()
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(() => {
     this.updateUI();
     this.setState({ refreshing: true });
 }, 2000);
})

return promise
}
```

Now when I pull the screen down, it does not stay for 2 seconds (Refreshing animation does not stay for 2 seconds) but immediately hide and refresh the UI.

**Problem**

What am I missing here? How can I keep the refreshing animation for 2 seconds and then call the functions `this.updateUI();` and `this.setState({ refreshing: true });`

Comment: It doesn't look like your are returning your promise in your refresh function. Is that just not shown?

Comment: @ageoff Sorry I missed some part of the code when updating. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve();
    reject(new Error("Error!"));
  }, 2000);
promise.then(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
     this.updateUI();
     this.setState({ refreshing: true });
  }, 2000);
})
```

Comment: Started to give me a warning ‘Unhandled Promise’

Comment: The error is a Unhandled Promise Rejection - You don't have a function to handle a rejection. You should add a reject argument to the promise function, and call ```reject()``` accordingly. I'll update my answer with how to do so.

Comment: And if the promise is being rejected, there should be an error somewhere else in your code, in the way you handle the promise.

Comment: As I know rejecting this wouldn't be a good thing right? I didn't get that warning in my code.

Comment: It doesn't appear in the code, only when you run it

Answer (score 0):

From the example in the github:

```
_refresh () {
    // you must return Promise everytime
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        // some refresh process should come here
        this.setState({cards: this.state.cards.concat([this.state.cards.length + 1])})
        resolve(); 
      }, 2000)
    })
  }
```

It seems you might be resolving the promise and then trying to do more... the promise should not resolve until the updating functions have been called. So I would try something like this:

```
_refresh(context) {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.updateUI();
      this.setState({ refreshing: true });
      resolve()
    }, 2000);
  })
  return promise
}
```

Comment: Maybe it was just a copy and paste issue, but there is no closing ')' on the new Promise() before return (updated my answer). Just another guess as it seems ti should be working and I would assume it wouldn't run with that syntax error.

Comment: Oh sorry. I again missed a bracket. But I didn’t just copy and paste your code. It works fine. But doesn’t do what I want.  :(